# RoundedImageView - add padding without cropping the image

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, drawable, rounded-corners

I am using RoundedImageView by vinc3m1 and I am trying to create an image that has a bitmap in it.
I want the ImageView to be rounded but not the bitmap I place into it,  like in this pic:
[image]

However, this is the result I am getting:
[image]

I use padding on the RoundedImageView to achieve this, the View is in a View which contains it and a label; I use the padding in code like this:

`int dpPadding = Utils.dpToPx(25);
        view.getImage().setPadding(dpPadding,dpPadding,dpPadding,dpPadding);`

and I see the padding, but I don't want the image inside to have the rounded corners, only the background.

Though it might not be the best way, can any one help?

Comment: You don't need to use that `RoundedImageView`, for this. Just use a round png image in a normal ImageView.

Comment: post some xml and java code for this relative problem. where are you giving padding values? how do we know?

Comment: unfortunatly i am working in an existing project and i dont have the time to replace all of the components, also, the png i am getting will not be rounded, added more details to my question.

Comment: Then simply scale down your image and add a border to it (to fill the space left by the scaling). Then save it and use it in your `RoundedImageView`.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein you mean scale down my bitmap? i can do it using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap, but how to i add the border to it?

Comment: You can create a "white" image with the original size and then combine the two images.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein your solution worked great for me, would you like to write it as an answer so that i can accept it as the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale down your image and add a border to it (to fill the space left by the scaling).

You can do it using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`.

To add the border to it, you can create a "white" image with the original size and then combine the two images by overlaying them.

Then save it and use it in your RoundedImageView.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this...

public class RoundImage extends Drawable {
      private final Bitmap mBitmap;
      private final Paint mPaint;
      private final RectF mRectF;
      private final int mBitmapWidth;
      private final int mBitmapHeight;

      public RoundImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
            mBitmap = bitmap;
            mRectF = new RectF();
            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            final BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
            mPaint.setShader(shader);

            mBitmapWidth = (int) 240;
            mBitmapHeight =  (int) 240;
      }

      @Override
      public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawOval(mRectF, mPaint);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
            super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
            mRectF.set(bounds);
      }

      @Override
      public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
            if (mPaint.getAlpha() != alpha) {
                  mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
                  invalidateSelf();
            }
      }

      @Override
      public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
            mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
      }

      @Override
      public int getOpacity() {
            return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
      }

      @Override
      public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
            return mBitmapWidth;
      }

      @Override
      public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
            return mBitmapHeight;
      }

      public void setAntiAlias(boolean aa) {
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(aa);
            invalidateSelf();
      }

      @Override
      public void setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) {
            mPaint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
            invalidateSelf();
      }

      @Override
      public void setDither(boolean dither) {
            mPaint.setDither(dither);
            invalidateSelf();
      }

      public Bitmap getBitmap() {
            return mBitmap;
      }
    enter code here

}


// Use like this
imageview.setBackgroundDrawable(new RoundImage(bitmapimage));
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this method to add some padding to my image :

.RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

```
    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@color/transparent"
        app:riv_border_color="@color/colorWhite"
        app:riv_border_width="2dip"
        app:riv_corner_radius="25dp"
        app:riv_oval="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listimage"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/search" />
</RelativeLayout>`
```